# Maven RESTEasy jboss .war deployment failed

Tags: java, rest, maven, jboss, netbeans-7

I am self learning the RESTEasy, to be built with Maven and to be deployed in jBoss and later on to integrate it with Jenkins.

Currently I have created a very simple RESTEasy webservice and built it with maven. I've got a `.war` file and exploded war(which is "unzipped" folder of the war I believe), a `1.0 snapshot folder` with `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` folders inside of it in my netbeans project target folder.

I've installed jboss 7.x.x in my mac and successfully started and verified it's working on my `localhost:8080`. I copied my .war file to jboss7.x.x/standalone/deployments folder.

-Ran the server by: sh jboss-7.x.x.Final/bin/standalone.sh 
-Got some error such. 
-Stopped the jboss, copied the exploded war folder into the standalone/deployments folder and ran the server again.
-Still getting the error. 
-What am I missing?
-The error log:

```
00:12:18,315 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
00:12:18,316 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/HelloRESTEasy] startup failed due to previous errors
00:12:18,348 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

00:12:18,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "HelloRESTEasy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
00:12:18,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment HelloRESTEasy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war in 21ms
00:12:18,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

00:12:18,593 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./HelloRESTEasy: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
^C00:16:14,240 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
```

And when I access the `http://localhost:8080/HelloRESTEasy-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Hello/justin` I got a `404`.

Answer (score 0):

That log is not complete and you picked the least important part, but my experience on that suggest that your WAR has resteasy*.jar libs inside it. For jboss 7 your pom.xml at resteasy dependency you must put "`<scope>provided</scope>`", so when you compile and package that lib will be skipped.